# How can I print to console after button press?(Python 3.5)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5

When I run the code "15" is immediately printed to console. How can I get it to print after I press the button?

```
from tkinter import *
def mult(n):
    print (n*3)

top = Tk()
B1 = Button(top, text = "Enter Number", command = mult(5))
B1.pack()
top.mainloop()
```

Comment: Take a look at [Why is Button parameter “command” executed when declared?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767228/why-is-button-parameter-command-executed-when-declared).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function arguments are fully evaluated before calling the function.

Make it into a callable:

```
from tkinter import *
def mult(n):
    print (n*3)

top = Tk()
B1 = Button(top, text = "Enter Number", command = lambda: mult(5))
B1.pack()
top.mainloop()
```